# Properties of the probability distribution functions (PDF-s) for continuous distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, infinity

I am trying to figure out if there are some particular mathematical properties that PDF-s for continuous distributions follow.

Let's assume that we have some continuous random variable $X$ that is distributed according to PDF $p_x$. Let's also assume that mathematical expectation of the variable is finite. (1) Will it mean that $p_x$ does not have infinity values anywhere, meaning that no set of $x$ that has non-zero Lebesgue measure turns $p_x$ to infinity? (2) Will it also mean then that any function of $X$ will have a finite mathematical expectation, except for the functions that turn to infinity on the set of $x$-s that has non-zero measure under $p_x$-induced measure?

Comment: (1) is unclear: if there were a set of $x$ that had "non-zero Lebesgue measure turns $p_x$ to infinity" then the distribution would not have a density. What would you say about a distribution with density $\frac{k}{\sqrt{|x|}$ on [-1,1]$ for suitable $k$?

Comment: That final point should have been: What would you say about a distribution with density $\frac{0.25}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ on $[−1,1]$ for suitable $k$?

Comment: So you mean that it can be a distribution with PDF that gets to infinity?

Comment: So long as it is positive, and integrates to $1$ over the support, it can be a density; having a finite expectation is an unrelated point

Comment: Sure, but that is basically exactly my point - is there some general characteristic of how functions that integrate to 1 look like? You gave a nice example with one critical point and bounded support, but can we have multiple critical points?

Comment: Yes - for example just take a mixture distribution of those with a single critical point.  You have even have the critical points dense on the real line

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Makes sense. But what about your first comment where you told that non-zero measure set where p_x is infinity would mean that distribution does not have density? Will not be infinite combination of such single critical point distributions be like this?

Comment: Not if the infinite combination was for example with critical points at all the rationals, as that would be a set with measure zero